# How to write a text file in java in which there is no cr character at the end of each line

Tags: java, carriage-return

I need to write a txt file in Java with no carriage return charcter at the end of each line.
Already I am using *PrintWriter*. But the output is as follow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XGf8.jpg)

I need it to be like the following picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19UEA.jpg)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to extend the `PrintWriter` class and override the `println()` method.

```java
public class UnixStylePrintWriter extends PrintWriter {
    @Override
    public void println() {
        write('\n');
    }
}
```

Then use this instead of the normal `PrintWriter`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly. I just added it to my code in this way:   writer = new PrintWriter("file.txt", "ASCII") {
    @Override
       public void println() {
           write('\n');
       }
   };